# Plot from data containing "e"

Tags: plotting, import

I have data as a "dat" file exported from matlab in this format:

```
   0.0000000e+00   5.0251170e-10
   6.6680005e-02   2.9928438e-08
  1.3336001e-01   3.2211615e-08
  2.0004002e-01   2.5819088e-08
  2.6672002e-01   1.9912510e-07
  3.3340003e-01   1.2164600e-08
  4.0008003e-01   3.3591592e-07
  4.6676004e-01   3.7976813e-07
  5.3344004e-01   1.0210168e-07
  6.0012005e-01   1.1753486e-06
 6.6680005e-01   1.7250708e-07
 7.3348006e-01   1.2378948e-06
 8.0016006e-01   1.9807977e-06
 8.6684007e-01   1.3961595e-07
 9.3352007e-01   4.6064945e-06
 1.0002001e+00   1.3926179e-06
 1.0668801e+00   3.8312722e-06
 1.1335601e+00   1.0100186e-05
 1.2002401e+00   3.2600501e-08
 1.2669201e+00   2.2926305e-05
 1.3336001e+00   1.4471191e-05
 1.4002801e+00   2.0777995e-05
 1.4669601e+00   1.3401266e-04
 1.5336401e+00   4.9475277e-06
 1.6003201e+00   2.5085131e-03
 1.6670001e+00   3.2650080e-03
 1.7336801e+00   9.6810898e-05
 1.8003601e+00   2.0783125e-04
 1.8670401e+00   7.7972426e-06
 1.9337202e+00   4.5902776e-05
```

But I want to plot them in 2 dimensions as semilog of the second column versus the first one as x axis. but there is letter "e" in data how can remove them and access to correct number to plot them because in this format I can't plot them!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your snippet of `Data` in file `my.dat` and in the same dir a Mathematica file for example `00.nb`,

```
toi = Import["my.dat", "Table"];
```

See also [Import](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html).

If speed is important see [OpenRead](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) and [ReadList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html):

```
moi = OpenRead["my.dat"];
data = ReadList[moi, {Number, Number}];

ListLogPlot[{toi}]
```

[image]

```
ListLogPlot[{data}, Mesh -> All, 
MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[Large], Red], Joined -> True, 
Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You must [`Import`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) the file using the [`"Table"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/Table.html) format.